# Windows Batch : query wmic computersystem get model if equals true continue with windows batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, wmic

Looking to write a script that will query wmic computersystem get model and if the value is true continue with batch file if not true echo Un-compatible system exiting, this is what i have so far

```
    @echo off

        for /F "skip=1" %%? in ('wmic computersystem get model') do "(

      if %%?' equ Test' ('goto start') else (

      if %%?' equ test1' ('goto start') else (

      if %%?' equ test2' ('goto start') else (

      if %%?' equ test3' ('goto start') else (

      echo un-compatible System Exiting...>nul)))))"

:start

start of script
```

im generally ok with scripting but never used if statements so kinda lost on this one.

Any help will be very welcomed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in (
        'wmic computersystem get model /value'
    ) do for /f "delims=" %%b in ("%%~a") do for %%m in (
        "model1" "model2" "model3" "model4"
    ) do if /i "%%~b"=="%%~m" (
        set "model=%%~m"
        goto start
    )

    echo un-compatible system
    goto :eof

:start
    echo Start of script for model [%model%]
```

Where the `for` loops are

- `%%a` to retrieve the model
- `%%b` to remove the ending carriage return in the value returned (`wmic` behaviour)
- `%%m` to iterate over the list of allowed models

If any of the allowed models matches the one retrieved with `wmic`, the code jumps to the start label, else, the inner `for` loop ends and as no match has been found the script ends.

This can be simplified as

```dos
>nul (wmic computersystem get model |findstr /i /l /c:"model1" /c:"model2" /c:"model3")||(
    echo un-compatible system
    goto :eof
)
echo compatible system
```

Where a conditional execution operation is used to determine if the `findstr` command fails to found any of the models and cancel the execution.

Of course, you can use the cascade of `if /else`, but the syntax is a little different

```dos
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in (
    'wmic computersystem get model /value'
) do for /f "delims=" %%b in ("%%~a") do (
    if /i "%%~b"=="test1" goto start 
    if /i "%%~b"=="test2" goto start 
    if /i "%%~b"=="test4" goto start 
)
echo un-compatible system
goto :eof
```

or

```dos
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in (
    'wmic computersystem get model /value'
) do for /f "delims=" %%b in ("%%~a") do (
           if /i "%%~b"=="test1" ( goto start 
    ) else if /i "%%~b"=="test2" ( goto start 
    ) else if /i "%%~b"=="test3" ( goto start
    ) else (
        echo un-compatible system
        goto :eof
    )
)
```

or

```dos
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in (
    'wmic computersystem get model /value'
) do for /f "delims=" %%b in ("%%~a") do (
    if /i "%%~b"=="test1" ( 
        goto start 
    ) else if /i "%%~b"=="test2" ( 
        goto start 
    ) else if /i "%%~b"=="test3" ( 
        goto start
    ) else (
        echo un-compatible system
        goto :eof
    )
)
```

or whatever other combination/style that better fits your code, but you have to take in consideration that the placement of the parenthesis matters. The `if` opening parenthesis needs to be on the same line that the `if` command. The `if` closing parenthesis needs to be in the same line that the `else` clause (if present). The `else` opening parenthesis needs to be in the same line that the `else` clause.

Comment: hi MC ND, thanks for your answer i tried the first option and replaced "model1" with my model "DH55HC__" but all i get is a blinking cursor

Comment: @ErikRichardson, i have directly copied and pasted the code in the answer, replacing one of the models with my computer model and it works. Have you made any additional change?

Comment: strange i tested it on some other machines i have around and it works perfectly thank you

Answer (score 2):

All @MC ND solutions are workfull.
But you can give this a try.

```
@echo off

::Defining the supported model
set $test="935gcm-s2c" "45687-98a" "57687-sdf"

for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic computersystem get model /value') do set "$Mod=%%a"
for %%a in (%$test%) do if /i %%a=="%$mod%" goto:ok
echo System not suppoprted
exit/b

:ok
echo System supported
```

Comment: My pc model is `HP Compaq 8100 Elite CMT PC`. Maybe you need some quotes.