# Windows batch - wmic computersystem get model - multiple models

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, if-statement

i have a question simular to [Windows Batch : query wmic computersystem get model if equals true continue with windows batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29387036/windows-batch-query-wmic-computersystem-get-model-if-equals-true-continue-with)

I have a batch file that uses wmic to get the system model number and will need to run a script based on the model number

Here is my script

```
REM @echo off
setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in (
    'wmic computersystem get model /value'
) do for /f "delims=" %%b in ("%%~a") do for %%m in (
    "HP t520 Flexible Series TC" "HP t610 WW Thin Client" "HP t620 Quad Core TC" "HP t630 Thin Client"
) do if /i "%%~b"=="%%~m" (
    set "model=%%~m"
    goto start
)

echo un-compatible system
goto :eof
:start
echo Start of script for model [%model%]
if [%model%]==[t520] start "" "C:\SWSetup\APP\Scripts\t520.bat" "C:\SWSetup\APP\Scripts\t520-wmi.bat"
if [%model%]==[t610] start "" "C:\SWSetup\APP\Scripts\t610.bat" "C:\SWSetup\APP\Scripts\t610-wmi.bat"
if [%model%]==[t620] start "" "C:\SWSetup\APP\Scripts\t620.bat" "C:\SWSetup\APP\Scripts\t620-wmi.bat"
if [%model%]==[t630] start "" "C:\SWSetup\APP\Scripts\t630.bat" "C:\SWSetup\APP\Scripts\t630-wmi.bat"
```

Here is the output of the cmd window

```
C:\SWSetup\APP\Scripts>setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

C:\SWSetup\APP\Scripts>for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %a in ('wmic computersystem get model /value') do for /F "delims=" %b in ("%~a") do for %m in ("HP t520 Flexible Series TC" "HP t610 WW Thin Client" "HP t620 Quad Core TC" "HP t630 Thin Client") do if /I "%~b" == "%~m" (set "model=%~m"
goto start
)

") do for %m in ("HP t520 Flexible Series TC" "HP t610 WW Thin Client" "HP t620Quad Core TC" "HP t630 Thin Client") do if /I "%~b" == "%~m" (set "model=%~m"
goto start
)

C:\SWSetup\APP\Scripts>for %m in ("HP t520 Flexible Series TC" "HP t610 WW Thin Client" "HP t620 Quad Core TC" "HP t630 Thin Client") do if /I "HP t520 Flexible Series TC" == "%~m" (set "model=%~m"
goto start
)

C:\SWSetup\APP\Scripts>if /I "HP t520 Flexible Series TC" == "HP t520 Flexible Series TC" (set "model=HP t520 Flexible Series TC" 
goto start
)

C:\SWSetup\APP\Scripts>echo Start of script for model [HP t520 Flexible Series TC] Start of script for model [HP t520 Flexible Series TC] t520 was unexpected at this time.

C:\SWSetup\APP\Scripts>if [HP t520 Flexible Series TC]==[t520] start "" "C:\SWSetup\APP\Scripts\t520.bat" "C:\SWSetup\APP\Scripts\t520-wmi.bat"
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: It is fairly obvious that the third `for` loop is outputting a full string, not just the `tnnn` part. You'll therefore need to adjust that third loop or further parse `%model%` or `%%m`, to refine it accordingly. The simplest way would be to change your `if` lines: `if not "%model:t520=%"=="%model%"...` . That all said, the entire thing could certainly be made shorter and more efficient/succinct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```bat
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion
Set "Model="
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in (
    'wmic computersystem get model /value'
) do for /f "delims=" %%b in ("%%~a") do Set "Model=%%b"

If not defined Model (Echo Can't get Model&Pause&Exit/B 1)

Echo:%Model%|findstr /i "t520 t620 t630 t640" >Nul 2>&1 ||(Echo None of the specified models&Exit/B 1)

for %%m in (t520 t620 t630 t640
  ) do @Echo:%Model%|findstr /i "%%m"  >NUL 2>&1 && (
    start "" "C:\SWSetup\APP\Scripts\%%m.bat" "C:\SWSetup\APP\Scripts\%%m-wmi.bat"
)
```

Comment: This worked I just needed to remove the following in the second last line after start ""

Answer (score 0):

Here's an untested idea.

```bat
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
CD /D "C:\SWSetup\APP\Scripts" 2>Nul || Exit /B
Set "Model="
For /F "Tokens=2" %%A In ('WMIC ComputerSystem Get Model^|Find "HP"'
) Do Set "Model=%%A"
If Exist "%Model%.bat" If Exist "%Model%-wmi.bat" (
        Echo Start of script for model [%Model%]
        Call "%Model%.bat" "%Model%-wmi.bat")
```